# PyCharm not moving focus to editor when opening file from Project Explorer

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

When in PyCharm's Project Explorer, if I hit <kbd>Return</kbd> on a file to open it, it is indeed opened in the editor, but focus is still on Project Explorer. If I start typing, it doesn't type into file but rather initiates a search in Project Explorer.

I have to manually click in editor to start navigating the file.

If I double click on the file in Project Explorer though, it works fine: it switches focus to that file in editor.

How can I get the same behavior when hitting the <kbd>Return</kbd> key?

I guess that behavior is probably the same in IntelliJ IDEA and other Jetbrains products

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to change keyboard setting for `Jump to source` to be `Return` instead of, or in addition to, `F4`